# Perl6: how to use <alpha> in user-defined character class or range?

Tags: regex, range, match, raku

I am trying to match any alphabetical characters and "," or ";" and I am trying to use "   <:L>     Alphabetic characters" according to the documentation https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes . However, the compiler complains. What is the proper way to do it without using a..zA..Z ?

```
say "a,b,c;d,e;xyz" ~~ m/ <[ <alpha> \, \; ]>+ /;
```

Error message:

```
Potential difficulties:
    Repeated character (a) unexpectedly found in character class
    at C:\Users\Guest\Documents/avg.pl:128
    ------> ay "a,b,c;d,e;xyz" ~~ m/ <[ <alpha> \, \<HERE>; ]>+ /;
```

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a sub-rule like `<alpha>` inside an [Enumerated Character Class](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges) (the `<[ ... ]>` syntax). An example of a correct enumerated character class would be `<[abc]>` to match the characters 'a', 'b', or 'c'. You had written an enumerated character class that began `<[ <alpha> ...`. This enumerates characters '<', 'a', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a' -- and at that point the compiler complains, saying "Repeated character (a) unexpectedly found in character class".

> What is the proper way to do it

Add the appropriate [Unicode property](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties) (`:L`) to an enumerated character class containing `,` and `;` like so:

```perl6
say "a,b,c;d,e;xyz" ~~ / <+ :L + [,;] >+ /;
```

The doc we've both linked gets closest to explaining this (super tersely) near the bit that says "one can write <:Ll+:N>". Note that the syntax is  finnicky about whitespace. (If you get it wrong it'll typically fail to match.)

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Brad, I edited your answer per @RBT's request without leaving you time to edit it yourself. Are you happy that I did so or would you prefer I give you a day or whatever to make such edits yourself?

Comment: @raiph If it mattered to me, I would have done so before posting.

Comment: Cool. Just checking.

Comment: Thank you raiph and Brad Gilbert !! You have helped me to improve my perl6 light saber skills :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can combine with <alpha> too:

```
say "a,b,c;d,e;xyz" ~~ m/ <[,;] + alpha>+ /
```

As mentioned in another answer, the [Enumerated character classes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges) documentation describes combining character classes.

Comment: Thank you mr_ron ! It works ! My initial difficulty was about how to use <[ ]> along with the angle brackets of <alpha> . Thanks.